# How to get the list elements using list inside another list in java

Tags: java, list

I have a list like this
List contains set of dtime,uptime values.I want to get the list items i.e., dtime into one and 
uptime into another variable.Likewise I want to get all the dtime and uptime pair values seperatly into 
the variables using for loop in java.How can I achieve this.Is it possible list or vector?Please help me.
    Pseudo code

```
List.get(0).get(0)-->gives 1st dtime
List.get(0).get(1)-->gives 1st uptime

List.get(1).get(0)-->gives 2nd dtime
List.get(1).get(1)-->gives 2nd uptime
```

And so on..

How to implement this with for loop I am not getting.I am new to java>please help me..

Comment: .. This really isn't much of a question. Can you show us the code you've tried, and articulate better what it is that you want?

Comment: Let us see the code you have tried so we can help.

Comment: A piece of code describing your problem would be helpful.

Comment: which kind of variable , array or simple variable

Comment: Does not look like job of List. Please make question more clear and easy to understand and provide sample code.

Comment: here dtime is double type and uptime is timestamp type variable

Comment: @user2365917 check now my answer

Answer (score 3):

First Convert That ArrayList into Object[] array then get the value like given below code...driver_ModelsObj is an array convert that into drives object array then get the value from inside the array.

```
for(int indx=0;indx<driver_ModelsObj.size();indx++){
                Object[] drivers=(Object[]) driver_ModelsObj.get(indx);
                String Device_ID=drivers[0].toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your list is as below

```
List list = [[1],[2],[3]];
```

We can retrieve the each value as below.

```
((List)list.get(0)).get(0); //This will retrieve value 1
((List)list.get(1)).get(0); //This will retrieve value 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ,Let say you have variables like

```
            double dtime;     
            Timestamp tp;
```

And listofresults is coming from query results.

```
listofresults = results.getResultList();
```

If list is coming from query then put it in the loop this way in the condition of for loop

```
    for(int i=0;i< listofresults.size() ;i=i+2)
    {
        dtime=(double) listofresults.get(i);       
                                   //cast because the value is of object type
        tp=(TimeStamp) listofresults.get(i+1);
                                 //cast because the value is of object type
        //do something with these variables 

    }
```

Comment: thank you.but my list contains the values returned from a query.        String query="select dtime,uptime from sample"; and result I am storing after executeQuery into a list.So I need list values seperately now.

Comment: I did not get you.Please help me.I have a query "select dtime,up_time from sample". And It will return some set of records having dtime,up_time and I am storing these values into a list.How they will be stored inside a list.like array [0][0] and [0][1] positions or anyother format

Comment: @user2365917 if you are putting into list , then it will be in incremental manner , or the order in which result of query is coming ,

Comment: @user2365917  iterate it and get the index at what index it is having the double value and timestamp value , from your question , it seems you are having list of list , list.get(0).get(0);

Comment: is this the order? like list[0][0]= dtime1,[0][1]= uptime1 and     list[1][0]=dtime2,[1][1]= uptime2 and so on.Am I correct?

Comment: @user2365917 that is not the way in list , if it is list of list  , then you need to iterate for one list and for inner list as well , its not like 2d array ,

Comment: how can I achieve this with iterate list another list for getting my result  as above?can u please help me?

Comment: ok do like this for(i=0;i<nameoflist.size();i++) { System.out.println(nameoflist.get(i));}   post what it prints

Comment: @user2365917 its hard to know in this case :'(  see if you can post some more code on pastebin and give a link here

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use a domain object containing `uptime` and `downtime`.

For example,

```
public class Stats {
    int dtime;
    int uptime;
}
```

Then you can have a `List<Stats>` and access it like this:

```
mylist.get(0).dtime
mylist.get(0).uptime
mylist.get(1).dtime
mylist.get(1).uptime
```

Part of the (newer) Collcetions framework, `List` is almost always a better alternative than `Vector`

Answer (score 0):

```
List.get(0).get(0)-->gives 1st dtime
List.get(0).get(1)-->gives 1st uptime
```

Well, what you're doing here, is getting the list at position `0`, and getting item `1` from that list. In a `for loop` we can express this as:

```
for(int x = 0; x < List.size(); x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < List.get(x).size(); y++)
    {
         if(y % 2 == 0)
         {
             // It's a dtime object.
         }
         else
         {
             // It's an uptime object.
         }
    }
}
```

Before this, you could declare some lists of your own:

```
List<DTime> listD = new ArrayList<ATimeObject>();
List<UpTime> listUp = new ArrayList<UpTime>();
```

Now when you're cycling through, all you need to do is add the relevant object:

```
if(y % 2 == 0)
{
    listD.add(List.get(x).get(y));
}
else
{
    listUp.add(List.get(x).get(y));
}
```

Comment: Is it same with  iterate for one list and for inner list?

Comment: :List.get(x).get(y) is not allowed in java

Answer (score 0):

You should create a POJO like

```
public class TimeData {
    double dtime;
    Date uptime;
}
```

Then add each POJO to array list and then iterate it.

```
        List<TimeData> oList = new ArrayList<TimeData>();
        int nSize = oList.size();
        for(int i=0;i<nSize;i++){
          TimeData child = oList.get(i);
          // get value using getters

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a wrapper for it.

```
public class UpTimeDownTime {
  MyTimeDataClass downtime;
  MyTimeDataClass uptime;

  public UpTimeDownTime(MyTimeDataClass downtime, MyTimeDataClass uptime){
    this.downtime = downtime;
    this.uptime = uptime;
  }

  public MyTimeDataClass getDowntime () {
        return downtime;
    }

  public MyTimeDataClass getUptime () {
        return uptime;
    }

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    List<List<MyTimeDataClass>> List = ...;
    List<UpTimeDownTime> uptimeDowntime = new ArrayList<UpTimeDownTime>();
    for(List<MyTimeDataClass> timeList : List){
        UpTimeDownTime u = new UpTimeDownTime(timeList.get(0), timeList.get(1));
        uptimeDowntime.add(u);
    }
 }

}
```